# Compound interest Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

A college student starts a savings account with an initial balance of $\$0$. He plans to save money at a continuous rate of $\$200$ per week. Also, at every week he plans to increase this rate by $\$10$. (ex. At the 4th month he would be saving at a rate of $\$240$ per week). Additionally, the college student finds a bank account that pays continuously compounded interest at a rate of $4\%$ per year. Estimate the time it'll take for the college student to save $\$500,000$. 
Hint: set up and solve a differential equation and plot the solution to make the final estimate.

My attempt:

The differential equation is hard to set up.

Let $S =$ amount saved.

Let $t =$ time.

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{0.04}{52}(200 + 10t)$$

I tried this differential equation but it doesn't satisfy the initial condition.

Can someone help me come up with the differential equation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asked to build a differential equation ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It should be some recurrence equation hopefully !!!...

Comment: Yes, it does asks to build a DE.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\mbox{Let}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
b_{n} &:& \mbox{Balance after}\ n\ \mbox{weeks}.&& b_{0} = 0
\\[2mm]
s_{0} & : & \mbox{Initial week saving} & = & 200
\\[2mm]
\Delta s & : & \mbox{Amount added to the every week saving} & = & 10
\\[2mm]
r & : & \mbox{Bank interest} \pars{~\mbox{per one per week}~}
& = & {4/\pars{12\times 4} \over 100} = {1 \over 1200}
\end{array}\right.
$$
We assumed $4$ weeks per month.

> $$
> \begin{array}{rclc}
> b_{0} & = & 0
> \\
> b_{1} & = & s_{0}
> \\
> b_{2} & = & b_{1}\pars{1 + r} + \pars{s_{0}  + \Delta s}
> \\
> b_{3} & = & b_{2}\pars{1 + r} + \pars{s_{0}  + 2\Delta s}
> \\
> b_{4} & = & b_{3}\pars{1 + r} + \pars{s_{0}  + 3\Delta s}
> \\
> \vdots & = & \vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\vdots
> \end{array}
> $$

In general we have to solve:
$$
b_{n} = b_{n - 1}\pars{1 + r} + \bracks{s_{0} + \pars{n - 1}\Delta s}\,,\quad n=2,3,4,\ldots\,;\qquad b_{1} = s_{0}\tag{1}
$$

> Lets $\quad\ds{{\rm B}\pars{z} \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n}}\quad$ with
>   $\quad\ds{\verts{z} < {1 \over 1 + r}}$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n} &= \pars{1 + r}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}b_{n - 1}z^{n}
+s_{0}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}z^{n} + \Delta s\sum_{n = 2}\pars{n - 1}z^{n}
\\[3mm]{\rm B}\pars{z} - b_{1}z &= \pars{1 + r}\
\underbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n + 1}}_{\ds{=\ z\,{\rm B}\pars{z}}} +
s_{0}\,{z^{2} \over 1 - z} + \Delta s\,{z^{2} \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}}
\\[5mm]
\bracks{1 - \pars{r + 1}z}{\rm B}\pars{z}&
=s_{0}\,{z \over 1 - z} + \Delta s\,{z^{2} \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}}
\end{align}

> $$
> {\rm B}\pars{z}
> ={s_{0}\ z/\pars{1 - z} + \Delta s\ z^{2}/\pars{1 - z}^{2} \over 1 - \pars{r + 1}z}
> $$
>   $$
> b_{n}=
> \frac{\left[\left(r + 1\right)^{n} - n r-1\right]\Delta s  +
> \left[\left(r + 1\right)^{n} - 1\right] r\,s_{0}}
> {r^{2}}
> $$
>   $$
> \color{#66f}{\large b_{n}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large 12000\braces{1220\bracks{\pars{1201 \over 1200}^{n} - 1} - n}}
> $$

$$
b_{284} \approx 499,325.84\,,\qquad
b_{\color{#c00000}{\Large 285}} \approx 502,781.94\,,\qquad
b_{286} \approx 506,250.93  
$$

> $$
> \color{#c00000}{\Large 285} = \color{#66f}{\Large 5} \times 48
> + \color{#66f}{\Large 11} \times 4 + \color{#66f}{\Large 1}
> $$

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
5\ \mbox{years}, 11\ \mbox{months and $1$ week}.  }
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! However, the different notations and the method you used is confusing to me. Do you know how to form a differential equation for this problem and possibly the general solution?

Comment: @Wade You won't have a differential equation because your problem is a discrete one ( you're talking about $\color{#c00000}{\large 1}$ week, $\color{#c00000}{\large 2}$ weeks, $\color{#c00000}{\large 3}$ weeks, etc... ). If you want to have a differential equation you have to take the time interval between deposit as going to zero with some suitable limits for all the involucrated variables. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't there 52 weeks in a year ?

Answer (score -3):

Solution as an image:

[image: Solution]

Final Answer:

[image: Final Answer]

Comment: Please learn $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference